# why should it have German values eroded or why should it has German values eroded?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

On facebook there is a post that says:

> The German Chancellor has called for a full-face veil ban in Germany.

In a comment, someone said:

> Yes i agree. Ms Merkel, Germany has been a beacon to help refugees but
>   why should it *have* German values eroded because of the good will the
>   Germans have shown.

Now, is it correct to say why should it *have* German Values .... ? (Why not *has* since *it* is a singular noun ?)

And how can we rewrite this sentence without this  structure?

Thank you

Comment: "It *have*" is correct. When *should/shall* helps a verb, the verb should be infinitive.

Comment: Oh, I missed something. Since it's not a question, you'd better write *"why it should have.."*

Comment: I would prefer "... but why should it have *eroded German values* because of the good will the Germans have shown." because *values* is the object of *eroded*, this would be more straightforward. As you wrote the example, *have* is not the right verb to use, because a ban can *cause* something but can't *have* something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"(Germany has been a beacon to help refugees) but why should *it* have German values eroded because of the good will the Germans have shown."

1. The first segment of the sentence is an independent clause -- it can stand alone, i.e. be a complete sentence.
2. If the clause is removed, it becomes clear that the ending punctuation should be a question mark. The sentence is a question and not a statement.

The "it" is problematic because of the distance from the antecedent -- Germany. And as the questioner points out, "Germany *has* values" while "Germans *have* values" even though "have" happens to be correct is this case because it IS a question and not a statement.

So it can be correctly rewritten either, "Why should Germany have its values eroded...?" or "Why should Germans have their values eroded...?"